# How To Call Controller Action or Controller Function From Views Or Any Location

Tags: cakephp, html-helper

I wanted to call controller action or controller function from view file.
but i know `$this->element()` is not very good for my work , because i should create element file in element directory .
there is way that i Call Controller Action or Controller Function From Views .
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `requestAction(string $url, array $options)` to retrieve data. Read [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/991/requestAction) on how to use it.

And note that it is not a recommended approach, since it can affect your app's performance.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i just use `requestAction()` in controller or i can use it in view?
thanks matyas.

Comment: you can use it in a view - as exemplified in the second code section at the link i gave you above ;)